# How can I filter a dstore using the contains method?

Tags: dojo, dstore

I have a dgrid populated with a dstore plain old Memory collection, that I am trying to filter using the 'contains' filter method. The store data looks something like this:

```
[
    {id:"25", users: ["13", "15"]},
    {id:"347", users: ["13"]},
    {id:"653", "users":["13", "17"]}
]
```

I want to retrieve all the records where a given user is in the users array. From my understanding, I was expecting to be able to set up a filter like `new Filter().contains('users', '15');` and set that as the collection for the grid, leaving one row (id = '25') in this example. However, I am left with 0 rows. I have also tried providing a regular expression for the filter, instead of just value matching, like `new Filter().contains('users', new RegExp('^15$'));` however this doesn't filter out any rows.

I am using dojo v1.10.4, dgrid v1.0.0 and dstore v1.1.1.
Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hj6euac5/6/) demonstrating my problem.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I also tried the same but was facing the same problem. Eventually, I had to override the `filter` method for the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing users as an array, that is why you cannot use

```
new Filter().contains('users', '15');
```

If you want to use .contains than you will have to use it like this:

```
new Filter().contains('users', ['15']);
```

a.k.a you have to check by providing an array, not a string.

Comment: This works and is something I wouldn't have though of doing! It's not mentioned in the documentation that the value to match should (or could) be provided as an array. The example from [sitepen](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2015/04/17/dstore-1-1/) says to search for products with a tag of "spring" to do `var filteredCollection = store.filter(new store.Filter().contains('tag', 'spring'));` and likewise providing an array as the value is not mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/docs/Collection.md). Thankyou :)